# How to add Time Capsule to neighbor's über fast network

Tags: network, time-capsule

I wish to add my Time Capsule to my neighbor's über fast network. I have their permission and WiFi password. But their router is non-Apple.

What are my options? One is an ethernet connection to their router with my Time Capsule and configure as a roaming network.

Are there other options that would allow me to physically keep the Time Capsule in my house?

Comment: Keeping the Time capsule in your home and connecting it WiFi to the neighbors Netgear router? I do not think so!

Comment: If you connect it with Ethernet cable directly to the router then yes!